# Accessing a JavaScript variable I can see in the console

Tags: javascript, ajax, console

I am helping to develop a WordPress website. One of the website's plugins "returns" a JavaScript object named `FWP`. The reason that I put "returns" in quotations is because I'm not clear what returns means. In other words: I'm unclear where `FWP` is stored.

I can see this object in Chrome's developer console by typing `FWP` in the console, which then displays the object in the console. 
But this all happens in the Chrome developer console. I'm not really doing anything to the variable in the webpage itself. I don't really have access to modify the real `FWP` object.

**Objective:** I would like to send this `FWP` object, as an input parameter, to a custom WordPress plugin that I have written in PHP.

I am confused how to actually grab the `FWP` object from the webpage, so that I can do things with it. 
I know that it's there...somewhere... in the webpage, because I can see it in Chrome's console. Right? I just don't know how to access it.

Is there a general way to access JavaScript variables that one can see in the Chrome developer console? Basically:

1) is there some place where JavaScript variables, visible in Chrome developer console, are stored in the webpage?

2) If so, is there a general method to access them?

Thanks for any guidance. I'm not new to WordPress or php or JavaScript, but I am having a blind spot with this question, and feel that I'm missing something that I haven't learned yet.

Comment: If you want to use this variable in javascript (client side) you can just use it however you want, just make sure your code is executed later. If you want to use it in PHP, that's different. If I were you I'd start with `grep -r 'FWP' .` in terminal launched from your plugins folder, find where it comes from and check the code.

Comment: Well..it's the "use it however you want" part where I get confused.  How do I even access `FWP`.

Comment: Just as you do in console, refer to it by `FWP` and that's it, try with `console.log(FWP)` and it should be logged into your console. However, since you want to access it in PHP, it would be inefficient to somehow send it back to PHP from JavaScript. Better find it in your PHP code, use `grep` or some other tool to find a PHP file where it's mentioned.

Comment: Refer to FWP where?

Comment: In your javascript code, I guess. You can do `echo "<scrip>your_code_here</script>";` from PHP (but it'll be better if you create a separate file). Just make sure that it goes after anything that creates `FWP` variable. But still, do you actually need it in javascript (client side) or in your php (server side)?